# Analytically continuing the series exponentially exponential series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, tetration

### Background

I was recently toying with a series:

$$ S = \exp(x)+ \exp(\exp(x))+ \exp(\exp(\exp(x)))+ \dots $$

Taking exponential both sides:

$$ \implies e^S = \exp(\exp(x)) \cdot \exp(\exp(\exp(x))) \cdot \exp(\exp(\exp(\exp(x))))\cdot \dots $$

Now differentiating $ S $ with respect to $x$:

$$ \implies S' = \exp(x)+  \exp(x) \cdot \exp(\exp(x)) + \dots + \frac{e^S}{e^x} $$

Dividing both sides by $e^S$

$$ \implies S' e^{-S} = - \frac{de^{-S}}{dx}=  \frac{1}{\exp(x)} + \frac{1}{\exp{(\exp(x))}} + \frac{1}{\exp(\exp(\exp(x)))} + \cdots$$

### Questions

Originally $S$ does not converge, for say, $x = .01$ but the other series
$ S'e^S $ does converge. Can we use this fact to analytically continue the series?(Somehow?) As I am a physics undergraduate I am aware my construction is not rigorous. How would one make a rigorous construction?

Comment: There is a similar approach in this presentation about extending tetration to non-integers: http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/ucsb_2013_14/mathcs103_s2014/tetration_presentation.pdf

Comment: I suppose it is a sort of regularization of the original series, though likely not in the normal analytic continuation sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, the series diverges too fast for me to apply any normal tactics on it. A crazy variation of Borel summation might work, but definitely messy looking.

Comment: I've fiddled with the alternating series of this and have proposed a procedere to get a taylor series for this by employing the concept of Carleman-matrices and of Neumann-series with such Carleman-matrices. For the alternating series it seems like an -at least not completely nonsense- summation method. See http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/10_4_Powertower_article.pdf For a serious discussion of the concept see http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/IterationSeriesSummation_1.htm However I've not yet at least an approach for the non-alternating series. (Borel is not possible fwiw)

Comment: It might be inspiring to use a base for the exponentiation which would lead to convergence of the sequence (not of the series itself), like $b=\sqrt 2$ instead of trying $b=e$ immediately. Moreover, why dot you start the series with $e^x$ instead of $x$?

Comment: For the series evaluated at one of the infinitely many (complex) fixpoints of the exponential function (say $t_k$)  we get formally $S=t_k + t_k + ... $ Unfortunately all fixpoints are repelling so we cannot explore the behave when we apply small disturbances because also the single terms of the series begin to diverge soon. So even all this fixpoints define  singularities. Hmm...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms you might find this interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372106/does-this-functional-equation-hold

Comment: @MoreAnonymous - seen! Thx! Unfortunately I've currently no space for this. Perhaps next week, but don't really know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of "transseries" (see [Transseries for Beginners](http://www.math.ohio-state.edu/~edgar/preprints/trans_begin/)) provides a system of formal series and generalized series.  However, in that formalism, the terms of a series must grow (asymptotically) smaller.  Not larger, as in your example.  But a variant may be considered like this:
$$
T:= \exp(-x) + \exp(-\exp(x)) + \exp(-\exp(\exp(x))) + \dots
$$
This one does converge (very rapidly) so it is also a series in the usual sense.  And it makes sense to try your derivative computation on it.

A related object is
$$
U := 
\frac{1}{x\cdot\log(x)\cdot\log(\log(x))\cdot\log(\log(\log(x)))\cdots}
$$
which may be considered the "boundary case" between convergent integrals  and divergent integrals (or series).

Comment: What did you mean by "it makes sense to try your derivative computation on it"? I thought you meant $e^S = \int -T dx$ ... Can't we define $S$ as this?

Comment: I mean you really can compute $T'$ term-by-term as you tried to do with $S'$.  And no, $\int (-T)\;dx$ will be an actual transseries, not your $e^S$.